# How to get the different column in similar rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
ID NAME LOCATION OCCUPATION IND
1   A     XYZ      QWE       1
1   A     WER      QWE       1
2   B     ERT      NBV       1
2   B     ERT      BVC       1
3   C     RTY      VCX       1
```

As you can see there are a few similar rows that differ only in the value in one/two columns. How can I get to know which column(s) is the differentiator in between similar rows i.e rows with same `ID`?
Any indicator of the column name in any way works.

Answer (score 0):

You extract each row as a list and compare elements.

```
size = len(row(1))
diff = [row1[i] != row2[i] for i in range(size)]
```

This gives you a sequence of Booleans, `True` where the elements differ.  Now check how many elements are the same:

```
if 1 <= sum(same) <= 2:
```

Now, simply return the indices of the `True` elements.

You should be able to handle the coding from here.